# An "outside the box" sequence

Tags: lateral-thinking, letter-sequence

I found a small letters sequences on Stack Exchange, but some elements are missing :

```
T H B C D L PP WH ?? M CU ?
```

### Question

What are the missing elements ?

### Hints

Hint 1 :

> Some elements I wrote can help you.

Hint 2 :

> Every ? is a letter.

Hint 3 :

> Think outside the box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> T H B C D L PP WH **AI** M CU **F**

This is from

> [image: the links at the top of the footer]
>  the first letters of the links across the top of the site footer

Comment: That was fast. Veeery fast. You got it !

Comment: @Somo145 Really Awesome !!!

Comment: @Therandomguy You have to be quick here!

Comment: Yeah, but i also need to increase difficulty on my questions D:

Comment: What gave it away to you?

Comment: @CodeNewbie The first sentence 'on Stack Exchange' suggested it wasn't just this site and the third hint (I read them all because they were there at first posting) made me look around the outside of the site, at which point I noticed the links.

Comment: @CodeNewbie - I had the right thought (outside the box, so I looked round the edges of the website page) but I only looked at the header, I didn't think of the footer as it was off-screen.